# How can we access type and subtypes of enum in java?

Tags: java, enums

I need to implement the following using `enum`.

```
import java.util.*;

/**
 *
 * @author mukesh
 */
public class MyTest {
private List<SubTypes> subTypes = new ArrayList<SubTypes>();
    enum Types {
        PercentArea, StackedArea, ChartSubType3;
    }

    enum SubTypes {
        PERSENTAREA1(Types.PercentArea),
        PERSENTAREA2(Types.PercentArea),
        PERSENTAREA3(Types.PercentArea),
        STACKAREA1(Types.StackedArea),
        STACKAREA2(Types.StackedArea),
        STACKAREA3(Types.StackedArea);           

        Types t;
        private SubTypes(Types t) {            
                this.t = t;
            }
        }

        public List<SubTypes> getSubTypes() {
            return Collections.unmodifiableList(subTypes);
        }    

    public static void main(String[] args) {               
        /* How can i get SubTypes based on base type ??? */
    }}
```

**Example :**

Suppose in one combo I have `Types` - `PercentArea`, `StackedArea`, `ChartSubType3` etc. and if I select `PercentArea` then second combo can get sub types e.g. `PERSENTAREA1`, `PERSENTAREA2` etc.

Can any one guide me how do I can retrieve all the values of subtype for given types.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'How can i get SubTypes based on base type?'

Comment: @user3161880 suppose in one combo i have Types -PercentArea, StackedArea, ChartSubType3 etc. Suppose i select PercentArea then second combo can get sub types e.g. PERSENTAREA1,PERSENTAREA2 etc

Comment: Why not add the subtypes to the types directly: `PercentArea(SubTypes.PRESENTAREA1, SubTypes.PRESENTAREA2)` etc, rather than having the types as properties of the subtypes.

Comment: @AndyTurner Yes i can but it already used in many files so i don't want to change it and i want to define my own subtypes based on types.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68579907/140803

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need something like this

```
private static void getSubTypes(Types type)
{
    SubTypes[] values = SubTypes.values();
    for(SubTypes value : values)
    {
        if(value.t == type){
            System.out.println("found subtype "+ value);
        }
    }

}
```

hope this helps!

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for help. 1Q is this get only single values or multiple i think it will return only single value right.

Comment: due to for loop , it will give you all the values , if you want this method to return the answer found, store all values in a array and return that array

Comment: Glad to know @mukeshpatel

Answer (score 1):

You can use SubType cahce like follows:

```java
private static final Map<Types, List<SubTypes>> typesMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();   

public static void addSubType(Types type, SubTypes subTypes){
    List<SubTypes> subTypeList;
    synchronized (type)
    {
        subTypeList = typesMap.get(type);
        if (subTypeList == null){
            typesMap.put(type, subTypeList = new LinkedList<>());
        }
    }
    subTypeList.add(subTypes);
}

public static List<SubTypes> getSybTypeList(Types type){
    return typesMap.get(type);
}

enum Types {
    PercentArea, StackedArea, ChartSubType3;
}

enum SubTypes {

    PERSENTAREA1(Types.PercentArea), PERSENTAREA2(Types.PercentArea), PERSENTAREA3(Types.PercentArea), STACKAREA1(
            Types.StackedArea), STACKAREA2(Types.StackedArea), STACKAREA3(Types.StackedArea);

    Types t;

    private SubTypes(Types t) {
        this.t = t;
        addSubType(t, this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use the `values()` method on the enum to get all of the `Subtypes`, and then keep or discard as you please.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html